# How to mock supabase storage when performing integration - e2e tests

Tags: flutter, supabase, supabase-flutter

I'm writing a flutter app which uses Supabase as its backend. I'm using the bucket and messaging functionalities the following way:

```dart
  await Supabase.initialize(
      url: dotenv.get('SUPABASE_URL'),
      anonKey: dotenv.get('SUPABASE_ANON_KEY', fallback: ''),
      debug: false);
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );

...

    final downloadedTraining = await Supabase.instance.client.storage
        .from('general')
        .getPublicUrl('trainings/2023-04-17.pdf');
...
    final dt = await Supabase.instance.client.storage
        .from('general')
        .download('/trainings/2023-04-17.pdf');
...
```

And now I would like to mock the storage in order to always return an expected result when performing the e-2-e tests with patrol.

Is it possible mocking just what I need i.e. `storage.from('...').download`? How can I achieve it?